# how to use WP 8 and Azure service bus topic communication?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a simple communication between WP 8 and Azure service bus's Topic. I made a wp 8.0 type project from vs 2012 template. I referenced appropriate assembly (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed.dll) ( as mentioned at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.topic.aspx) via NuGet package manager. But Topic class is unresolved. Also if I try to include few others assembly such as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager, Install-Package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus  by NuGet. It fails and gives this error message:

'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I didn't find any example any kind of communication between WP 8 and Azure. I found only console example. Please guide me where can find something between WP 8 and Azure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error. What you're probably missing is to update your `NuGet` package manager to the latest version.

Go to Visual Studio File Menu --> Tools --> Extensions and Updates --> Updates --> Visual Studio Gallery --> NuGet --> Update and finally you'll need to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution!
Azure Service Bus doesn't support Windows Phone 8 project, you have to use 
Windows Azure Service Bus Management Library 0.9.3-preview
Here's a URL:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus/0.9.3-preview

I hope it helps!